# Concurrent database session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, database-concurrency

How does amazon maintain the session between devices while adding the products to the cart?

How can we implement that in ROR?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, but I would just store the cart in your database on a per-user basis. This way when the user has multiple active sessions they will see the same cart.